# calculation of work time and lunch time of individual days - php/mysql

Tags: php

example:

if a user come office in morning, go to lunch, come office after lunch, and then go to home then how we can calculate work time and lunch time

[ currently i have 'start time', 'end time' and total time including lunch time ]

I need 'total time' excluding 'lunch time' order by individual dates

Please help me!

Comment: End time - start time - lunch time...? What exactly are you stuck on? Math? Number/time conversion?

Comment: Select endtime-(startime+lunchtime) FROM your_table WHERE your condition. Is this wath you want. Be more specific. I sincerilly guessed that you want what i said before

Comment: If it's the date/time math that is the problem, you should probably be looking at the PHP date and time functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two options here.

1) If you know how long lunch took, subtract that time from the total. Done.

2) If you only know when lunch started and ended, use those times to determine how long lunch took. GOTO 1

Comment: All employees in/out data entry is fetching in this format:

logtype                            time     Date  
------------------------------------------------------
start_time [come office]           10:30    11-11-2010
end_time [go to lunch]             14:00    11-11-2010 
start_time [come back from lunch]  15:00    11-11-2010
end_time [out from office]         20:00    11-11-2010


Question:

I want to calculate 'start time', 'end time', 'time including lunch ' and 'time excluding lunch'

1. start time
2. end time
3. total time including lunch time
4. total time excluding lunch time